# Boundary operator of products and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose we have a triple of spaces $(X, A, A')$ and a couple $(B, B')$ with some assumptions about excisiveness. I wonder if the following diagram
\begin{array}{ccc}
H^n(A \times B \cup X \times B', A' \times B \cup X \times B') & \longrightarrow & H^{n+1}((X, A) \times (B, B')) \\
\downarrow & \nearrow \\
H^n((A, A') \times (B, B'))
\end{array}
is commutative, where the horizontal arrow is the boundary operator of the triple, the vertical is induced by inclusion and the diagonal one is the boundary operator in the relative MV-sequence with $(X_1, A_1) = (X \times B, X \times B' \cup A' \times B)$ and $(X_2, A_2) = (A \times B, A \times B)$ or maybe some other choice for $(X_1, A_1), (X_2, A_2)$ that gives a boundary operator between the same groups.

I'm trying to make the connection between G. W. Whitehead's book, page 67 (right before II.2.30) and page 150 in Spanier's text (5.6.6).

*Notation:* $(A, A') \times (B, B')$ is supposed to mean $(A \times B, A' \times B \cup A \times B')$.